# Javascript contact form doesn't execute/send email

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, contacts

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateform() {
            var inputbericht = document.forms["formulier"]["bericht"].value;
            var inputmail = document.forms["formulier"]["mail"].value;
            var inputvoornaam = document.forms["formulier"]["Voornaam"].value;
            if (inputvoornaam == null || inputvoornaam == "") {
                alert("Naam moet worden ingevuld!");
                return false;
            }
            if (inputmail == null || inputmail == "") {
                alert("E-mailadres moet worden ingevuld!");
                return false;
            }
            if (inputbericht == null || inputbericht == "") {
                alert("Een bericht moet worden ingevuld!");
                return false;
            }
        }


        </script>
```

```html
<form action="mailto:MYEMAIL" method="post" name="formulier" onsubmit=" return validateform()">

        <p>Naam: <input type="text" name="Voornaam"></p>
        <p>E-mailadres:  <input type="text" name="mail"></p>
        <p>Bericht: <br><br><textarea name="bericht" rows="5" cols="110"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden"></p>
        <br>
    </form>
```

I've changed my email with MYEMAIL to censor my email adres.
When filling in the form and clicking on submit, I don't receive any email.
It seems something isn't executed right, I think I should add something to the submit button, but I'm not quite sure what and why.

Comment: Add `return true;` at the end of your validation function, just before the closing `}`.

Comment: Okay I did this, no result.

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: For some reason, the console doesn't show anything, even when I don't enter for example my name and I get alert("False name"), nothing displays in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that approach won't work. You need to send the submitted data to a script of some sort which will then send it using a mail protocol.

If you wan't to use a full JavaScript solution there's always [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/). If you're using PHP, and your server supports it, you might use something like the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.